# Convert String to DateTime keeping datetime unchanged

Tags: c#, datetime

Have the below string which i want to convert to a DateTime in c# code.

```
string dateTime = "2017-03-29T17:51:44.8389637Z";
DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime);
```

The above code converts it to: 3/29/2017 10:51:44 AM
I lose about 7 hours with the conversion, how can i get the result as: 2017-03-29 17:51:44. I think it has something to do with culture..?

Please help.

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=what+is+utc

Comment: well I have to say is not common to send someone to *bing* something rather than *google it*

Comment: `DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToUniversalTime();`

Comment: Use the `DateTime.Parse` with the overload the specifies the `DateTimeStyles` so you can control whether the time is converted to UTC or is converted to local time. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey1cdcx8(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using DateTime.Parse to provided a more robust conversion:

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse("2017-03-29T17:51:44.8389637Z", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this happening is you have a date/time string that ends with a `Z`. This denotes that it is in UTC time. When you're converting to a DateTime, it is converting it to your local culture's time, so you're losing *exactly* seven hours, because your time zone is seven hours behind UTC.

According to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC),

> If the time is in UTC, add a Z directly after the time without a space. Z is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset. "09:30 UTC" is therefore represented as "09:30Z" or "0930Z". "14:45:15 UTC" would be "14:45:15Z" or "144515Z".

So, your `2017-03-29 17:51:44` string and your `3/29/2017 10:51:44 AM` are the exact same time, in different time zones.

EDIT: as others have said, just use `DateTime.Parse` to specify how you want the DateTime to be created.

Comment: Thank you jam23, much appreciate the detailed answer!

Comment: It's the kind of thing that makes perfect sense once you know it, but isn't always intuitive. Cheers.